# How to check if it's xx:00:00 with a timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, time, utc, leap-second

It seems that checking if it's xx:00:00 UTC/GMT is as simple as checking if  `timestamp % 3600 == 0`, with timestamp = number of seconds elapsed since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01 00:00:00). We can see it here:

```
import datetime 
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(3600*24*17000)
# 2016-07-18 02:00:00
```

But isn't this in contradiction with [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? Indeed, the number of seconds elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and 2016-07-18 02:00:00 is **not a multiple of 3600**, but **a multiple of 3600  + 26 leap seconds** (there have been 26 leap seconds between 1972 and now).

---

To be more precise: the number of elapsed seconds between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and 2016-07-18 02:00:00 is `3600*24*17000 + 26` **and not `3600*24*17000`**.

Comment: Many (most?) computer systems track [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Why do you need this? If it's to run some code at midnight (or another time of day), there are better ways.

Comment: @Thomas I do know `cron` and similar scheduling tools for Python but I don't need it for this, I just wanted to know how UNIX timestamp works.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `datetime.datetime` objects can not handle leap seconds since the `seconds` attribute is limited to the range 0..59:

```
In [19]: DT.datetime(2012, 6, 30, 23, 59, 60)
ValueError: second must be in 0..59
```

(There was a leap second just before midnight, 2012-06-30).

So Python's datetime system does not quite represent all times as they exist in the real world. It models a simplified world where no leap seconds exist.

See also: this [python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue23574) which was closed with status "won't fix".

The linked page shows [`mxDatetime`](https://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) as an alternative to `datetime.datetime` which can ([sort of](https://bugs.python.org/issue23574#msg244151)) handle leap seconds.

Comment: Yes, but this means that either 1) Python's datetime/timestamp is different than other UNIX timestamps implementations in other languages (that would be bad, and I think it's not the case) or 2) All UNIX timestamps implementations don't care about leap seconds in general. Then is there a slow "drift" between real time and time extracted from a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Per [Howard Hinnant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328382/how-to-check-if-its-xx0000-with-a-timestamp/48328495#comment83642427_48328382) all UNIX timestamps ignore leap seconds.

Comment: [It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328717/1422096) that it dosn't ignore them @unutbu, it does process them by jumping back the timestamp of 1 second when it appears.

Comment: @Basj: Perhaps I mispoke by saying UNIX timestamps ignore leap seconds. 
The UNIX timestamp is rolled back to account for the leap second. 
The problem is now you have two real moments in time represented by the same UNIX timestamp.
Python uses your system's `localtime` to convert the timestamp to a date which may or may not recognize leap seconds.
[This code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/datetime.py#L1440) shows Python 
squashing seconds >= 60 down to 59 seconds, thus ignoring leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Leap_seconds):

> When a leap second is inserted, which happens about every year and a half on average, the Unix time number increases continuously during the leap second, during which time it is more than 86,400 seconds since the start of the current day, **and then jumps back by 1 at the end of the leap second**, which is the start of the next day

```
1998-12-31T23:59:59.75  915 148 799.75
1998-12-31T23:59:60.00  915 148 800.00  # leap second here
1998-12-31T23:59:60.25  915 148 800.25
1998-12-31T23:59:60.50  915 148 800.50
1998-12-31T23:59:60.75  915 148 800.75
1999-01-01T00:00:00.00  915 148 800.00  # timestamp jumps back!
1999-01-01T00:00:00.25  915 148 800.25
```

So probably there's some code somewhere in [`datetime.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/datetime.py) that does this leap second detection + jumping back. There's a reference to "leap second" [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/datetime.py#L1440) but I can't see how it could detect if it's one or not.

```
import datetime 
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(915148799) #1999-01-01 00:59:59
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(915148800) #1999-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: Jumping back is one way that it can be done, but also look at the many implementations that implement a "leap smear" rather than a leap second. Google is only one example https://developers.google.com/time/smear of how smears are done. The Go language has chosen a different strategy https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/12914-monotonic.md 
The underlying problem is that different agencies have chosen different goals for what is important about how time should work http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/picktwo.html